# Changing parameters while plotting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code for plotting 3d scatterplot in python that updates after every 2 seconds (plot is dynamic). I wish to be able to adjust the values of some of the parameters on line (while plotting happens) based on which the plotting happens. Is it possible to give a textbox along with the plot from which we can take as input the required parameter value based on which this plot will then be subsequently modified?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib does not have a textbox (or other text entry) [widget](http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html).  To use a textbox, you would need to embed a matplotlib graph within a separate GUI framework.  To do this, decide on the GUI framework you want to use (qt, wx, gtk, or tkinter), and a textbox widget from the gui framework, and then add the plot from matplotlib.  This isn't difficult and there are lots of available examples, generally best found for each specific framework you're interested in.

There might also be other pure matplotlib approaches that could work for you, such as using a matplotlib slider widget, or you could directly capture keyboard events, but without knowing exactly what you're going to for, it's hard to say.